# get specific lines and data from textfile in python

Tags: python, text-files

I'm extremely new to python and I'm trying to learn. I have a text file containing this:

```
1 Lebron 30 5
1 Curry 29 8
1 Durant 20 4
2 Lebron 35 3
2 Curry 39 6
2 Durant 15 8
3 Lebron 25 6
3 Curry 30 5
3 Durant 21 5
```

I want to be able to input a name and get the first, third, fourth and a multiplication of the third and fourth column.

I know how to ask for the name, but I can't get further than that. I imagine something like a text split and a for loop.

This is what I have done so far

```
fileName = input("Enter the file name: ")
playerName = input("Enter the player name: ")

inputFile = open(fileName, 'r')
text = inputFile.read()

print("%4s % 8s % 10s % 12s" % \
        ("game", "Points", 
        "Assists", "PointsxAssists"))
words = len(text.split())
```

Comment: I got everything to work now, but does anyone know how I can summarize each column from my output?
I get this as output for Durant
Enter the player name: "Durant"
First three games of the year for Durant
game points assists p x a
1 20 4 80
2 15 8 120
3 21 5 105
21
The last number 21 is the last number in points. Does anyone know how I can add all three points columns together? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (assuming there are only 3 whitespaces on each line in the file):

```
file_name = input("Enter the file name: ")
filter_name = input("Enter a name for filtering: ")
filter_name = filter_name.lower()

with open(file_name) as f:
    print('Showing names that contain "{}"'.format(filter_name))
    print('{:4s} {:10s} {:10s} {:10s}'.format(
        'game', 'points', 'assists', 'p x a'))

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 0:
            game, name, col3, col4 = line.split()
            name = name.lower()

            if filter_name in name:
                col3 = int(col3)   # this may raise ValueError if it is not a valid int
                col4 = int(col4)   # this may raise ValueError if it is not a valid int
                product = col3 * col4

                print('{:4s} {:10d} {:10d} {:10d}'.format(
                    game, col3, col4, product))
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this though and it returns the following error message:     12     'game', 'points', 'assists', 'p x a'))
     13 
---> 14 with open(inputFile) as f:
     15     for line in f:
     16         line = line.strip()
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: You probably used `open()` before the `with open(...` line. You do NOT need to call open before that line.

Comment: So I do not get an error message now, however don't get any information from the textfile. 
Enter the file name: "basket.txt"
game points     assists    p x a
I want to be able to have an input for a name and get only the 3 games that player has played. If that makes sense. Thank you again I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Clueless added filtering to my answer. Is that what you need?